# How can i use Mobile Hardware components, like: MNotification, MCamera, MGeolocation, MAccelerometer?

Tags: php, android, html5builder

I am using Embarcadero's HTML5Builder for Android server mobile apps development.

How can i use Mobile Hardware components, like: MNotification, MCamera, MGeolocation, MAccelerometer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you mainly configure their properties at design time, and use JavaScript events (MPage’s or otherwise) to work with your hardware components. To get you started with client events, I recommend you to follow the [Hello World tutorial for client mobile applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/HTML5_Builder/en/Client_Mobile_Hello_World), but using a *server* mobile application instead.

Obviously, each mobile hardware component works differently. What is common about them is how to find out how to use them.

In the documentation there is a page, **[Mobile Hardware Components](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/HTML5_Builder/en/Mobile_Hardware_Components)**, with a list of hardware components. Most hardware components have a page of its own linked there.

**Note:** Links to the **RPCL Reference** in the documentation (*RPCL* is the HTML5 Builder PHP library) are broken. To access the reference documentation for a hardware component, create a mobile application, add the target hardware component to it, select the component and click **F1**.

Most hardware component pages in the wiki provide a section, **Help Resources**, with tutorials, video tutorials, links or references to sample applications, or links to the **PhoneGap documentation** (hardware components are based on [PhoneGap](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/HTML5_Builder/en/MNotification)).

In addition to properties and JavaScript events, sometimes you use JavaScript functions to interact with components. Those JavaScript functions are *not* listed in the (PHP) RPCL Reference, but they are listed in the wiki pages.

So, about the components that you mention:

- To use **[MNotification](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/HTML5_Builder/en/MNotification)**, you just need to define the `Message` property at design time, and call `ComponentNameNotification()` (for example, `MNotification1Notification()`) from a JavaScript event, such as `MPage`’s `OnLoad`, or from a `Button`’s `OnClick`.
- To use **[MCamera](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/HTML5_Builder/en/MCamera)**, you call `ComponentNameGetPicture()`, and define event handlers for `OnError` and `OnSuccess`.
- For **[MGeolocation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/HTML5_Builder/en/MGeolocation)** I recommend watching the video tutorial linked from the documentation.
- In the case of **[MAccelerometer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/HTML5_Builder/en/MAccelerometer)**, the sample application references on the documentation might be a good start point.

**Note:** You mention you will work on server mobile applications, so I think it’s worth mentioning that, while mobile hardware components do work on server applications, they only work when you deploy them with the *Mobile Deployment* wizard, as they are based on PhoneGap.

Comment: Do you expect an answer that provides a source code example of how to use every hardware component? Why don’t you just check out the sample applications distributed with HTML5 Builder?